# Get mail subject using applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm writing a script using the Mail applescript template (File > New from template > Mail > Mail Rule Action.scptd) but it doesn't seem like the examples in the template are working

```
using terms from application "Mail"
      on perform mail action with messages these_messages for rule this_rule
                tell application "Mail"
                          set the message_count to the count of these_messages
                          repeat with i from 1 to the message_count
                                    set this_message to item i of these_messages
                                    try
                                              set this_subject to (subject of this_message) as Unicode text
                                              if this_subject is "" then error
                                    on error
                                              set this_subject to "NO SUBJECT"
                                    end try
                            say this_subject
                          end repeat
                end tell
      end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

It says "no subject" even if the message has a subject. I'm using OS X 10.7.2 and Mail 5.1. Any suggestions?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722381/save-mail-attachment-from-applescript-in-lion)... there apparently are problems with Mail's Applescript capabilities in 10.7.

Answer (score 2):

I have this working under 10.8.2 (Mail 6.2) if it helps at all? This is the code I'm using:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        tell application "Mail"
            repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
                try
                    set this_subject to subject of eachMessage
                    if this_subject is "" then error
                on error
                    set this_subject to "No subject."
                end try
                say this_subject
            end repeat
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `delay 3` under `set this_subject to (subject of this_message) as Unicode text`. It may be that Mail doesn't have time to process the message to get the subject line before moving to the next command.

If this works, you may not need 3 seconds. You can experiment with decreasing the delay time. Note that you can use decimals, as in 1.8.